# why is this not printing out a grocery list? NSMuteableArray For fast loop enumeration

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsstring, nsmutablearray, nsarray

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSMutableArray *groceries;
        NSString *a = (@"loaf of bread");
        NSString *b = (@"stick of butter");
        NSString *c = (@"big ass cookie");

        [groceries addObject:a];
        [groceries addObject:b];
        [groceries addObject:c];

        for (NSString *d in groceries){
            NSLog(@"%@", d);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why is this not working? What is wrong? Thanks.
I cannot seem to figure it out at this moment, the for loop defiantly seems to be the hangup.

Comment: groceries is not initialized

Comment: `groceries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: Learn to use the debugger and step through this code looking at the value of each variable at each step. The problem will become quite clear.

Comment: Thank you the debugger is really useful i defiantly need to familiarize myself with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you didn't initialize `NSMutableArray`, it's is nil. Adding object  to non-initialized mutable array always give nil.

Firstly you need to initialize groceries:

```
NSMutableArray *groceries = [NSMutableArray new];
```

or more liked by me way:

```
NSMutableArray *groceries = @[].mutableCopy;
```

In your case, for example, you can declare so:

```
NSMutableArray *groceries = @[@"loaf of bread", @"stick of butter", @"big ass cookie"].mutableCopy;
```

Comment: In the second way why are you using the literal symbol @ then empty brackets then a period and mutableCopy method very confused... can you explain further

Comment: `[[NSArray alloc] init]` is equal to `[NSArray new]` and `@[]`,`[[NSMutableArray] alloc] init]` is equal to `[NSMutableArray new]` and `@[].mutableCopy`. Also `[NSDictionary new]` is equal to `@{}`, `[NSMutableDictionary new]` is equal to `@{}.mutableCopy`

Comment: It's simply shorter versions.

Comment: In your case, for example, you can declare so: `NSMutableArray *groceries = @[@"loaf of bread", @"stick of butter", @"big ass cookie"].mutableCopy;`

Comment: wow igor there are so many different ways to get the same result its rather amazing as well as daunting

Comment: well @MikeSchaf, if you satisfied an answer, you can accept it.